# how to extend the Elm mouse drag example to include several squares?

Tags: svg, elm

I have been trying to extend the click and drag example to get several squares instead of of just one http://elm-lang.org/examples/drag

The relevant part is the update:

```
type Msg
    = DragStart Position
    | DragAt Position
    | DragEnd Position


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  ( updateHelp msg model, Cmd.none )


updateHelp : Msg -> Model -> Model
updateHelp msg ({position, drag} as model) =
  case msg of
    DragStart xy ->
      Model position (Just (Drag xy xy))

    DragAt xy ->
      Model position (Maybe.map (\{start} -> Drag start xy) drag)

    DragEnd _ ->
      Model (getPosition model) Nothing



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  case model.drag of
    Nothing ->
      Sub.none

    Just _ ->
      Sub.batch [ Mouse.moves DragAt, Mouse.ups DragEnd ]
```

I changed the view so that it was Svg instead of a Div.  The model is the same (which is a selling point of the Elm architecture).

The dilemma is how to change the model and drag architecture to convey information about **which square is being clicked and moved**

```
type alias Model =
    { position : Position
    , drag : Maybe Drag
    }


type alias Drag =
    { start : Position
    , current : Position
    }
```

Instead I changed this model to include an abstraction called `Tile` which went nowhere:

```
type alias Model = { a: Tile, b: Tile, c: Tile }

type alias Tile =
  { position : Position
  , drag : Maybe Drag
  }

type alias Drag =
  { start   : Position
  , current : Position
  }
```

I thought it would be straightforward to merge all the update events to remember which square was clicked.  But I am totally lost and done for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elm does not allow you to iterate over a record. So good start would be to put the tiles in a `Dict`, which makes it easier to access and update individual tiles.
You would also need to keep track of which of your tiles is being dragged. And at any time, only one Tile can be dragged. So inside the `Drag` type seems like a nice place.

```
type alias Model = 
  { tiles : Dict Int Tile
  , draggedTile : Maybe Drag
  }

type alias Tile = Position

type alias Drag =
  { draggedTileId : Int
  , start   : Position
  , current : Position
  }
```

Your `DragStart` message would then also need to include the id of the Tile being dragged:

```
type Msg
    = DragStart Int Position
    | DragAt Position
    | DragEnd Position
```

Then in your `update`, whenever you get a `DragStart` message, you set the `draggedTile`, and store the id of the tile you get.
When a `DragAt` or `DragEnd` message comes in, you only read the position, and update the drag (and tile when the drag ends).

In your `view` function, include
`List.map viewTile (Dict.toList model.tiles)`

And add a helper to render each tile:

```
viewTile : (Int, Tile) -> Html Msg
viewTile (id, tile) = 
  ...
```

Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction..